# How can I use SQL IN?

Tags: sql

Using below query, I can get all the details from `table1` where `eid` is in the `employee` table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE eid IN (SELECT id FROM employee)
```

But I want to get all the details from `table1` where `eid` is in the `employee` table + eid=0 values.

This is because column id in employee table starts from 1, but some of the column eid in the table1 have the value of 0.

How can I make a query for that?

Comment: What do you mean by *where eid in employee table + eid=0 values*? Like where the `eid` and `id` have no values? Like they are null?

Comment: Or are you asking for where the `id` and `eid` are added together it equals 0?

Comment: @Ibrennan208 in employee table id start from 1, but there are some values in table1 eid=0, I want to get both one

Comment: Try this `select ... where eid in (SELECT id from employee) or eid=0`

Comment: Oh, then yes, @Ahmed had a good suggestion of using an `OR` to add an additional condition to your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use OR clause at the end

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE eid IN (SELECT id FROM employee) OR eid = 0;
```

This will return all eid from the employee table and the eid = 0 from table1